# Differentiation of integral (easy)

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $\beta\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ nice. I want to compute
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\int^y_{-\infty} (x-y)^\beta f(x)\text{d}x
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\int_y^\infty (x-y)^\beta f(x)\text{d}x
$$
I get to this point applying definition of differentiation
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\int^y_{-\infty} \frac{1}{h}((x-y-h)^\beta-(x-y)^\beta) f(x)\text{d}x+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int^{y+h}_{y} ((x-y-h)^\beta f(x)\text{d}x
$$
for the first case but then I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$\frac{d}{dy}\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,y)\text{d}x=f(y,b(y))b'(y)-f(y,a(y))a'(y)+\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f_y(x,y)\text{d}x$$